# How i can use effects with metadata without passing the property "type" from my service?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm learning ngrx and i'm trying to make a example using metadata (i'm following the NgRx documentation), my problem is that my service is reveiving the type of my action, and i need only the payload.

What i tried:

In my component i make a dispatch passing my user object:

```
public save() {
  const user: Usuario = this.formGroup.value;
  this.store.dispatch(saveUser(user));
}
```

This is my action:

```
export const saveUser = createAction('[Users API] Save User', props<Usuario>());
```

This is the effect that handle this action:

```
public saveUser$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(saveUser),
    mergeMap((action) => this.usuarioService.save(action))
  )
);
```

This is my service:

```
public save(data: T): Observable<any> {
  console.log(data);
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiPath}`, data);
}
```

My problem is that my service is receiving the type of my action and i need only the object user:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "nome": "naaame",
  "cidade": "ciiity",
  "type": "[Users API] Save User"
}
```

I try to pass a object in my action:

```
this.store.dispatch(saveUser({ user: user }));
```

But my service is an abstract class, i extend this class in my services to reduce repetead codes, so, in this class i can't use data.user because other services also extend this class and use the same function `save()`.

I also tried to remove the type from the object and return the service without this action:

```
  public saveUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(saveUser),
      exhaustMap((action) => {
        const userWithoutType = {...action}
        delete userWithoutType.type
        return this.usuarioService.save(userWithoutType);
      })
    )
  );
```

This way my service don't receive the type property, but i receive a error from the ngrx:

> ERROR Error: Effect "UsuarioEffects.saveUser$" dispatched an invalid
>   action: {"id":5,"nome":"wwww","cidade":"wewe"}
>
> ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property

Answer (score 2):

```
public saveUser$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(saveUser),
    mergeMap((action) => this.usuarioService.save(action.Usuario))
  )
);
```

Comment: hi, i try but i receive: 'Property 'Usuario' does not exist on type 'Usuario & TypedAction<"[Users API] Save User">'' and if i use "mergeMap" instead of exhaustMap, my request is maded twice

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/actions#writing-actions write your action with a property {Usario: User}

Comment: Something is dispatching the saveUser action a second time.

Comment: if i use a object and pass action.Usuario i don't have the property type, so i receive: Error: Effect "UserEffects.saveUser$" dispatched an invalid action: {"id":2,"nome":"wawa","cidade":"wewe"}